# Jest/Enzyme Unit Test on Axios Requests in ComponentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to perform some unit testing on my existing react application with Jest and Enzyme. I am totally new to this stuff and accurately I do not know how to approach such test scenarios. I know that to test API request calls I have to perform some "mocking", but how should I write the test for that?. What will be the steps that needs to be followed?

Following is the code snippet I am looking to test.

Home.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import FacilityModal from '../Table/FacilityModal';

class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    cities:[],
    name:''
  }
 
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/cities').then(res => {
      this.setState({cities:res.data})
      console.log("Oza" + JSON.stringify(res))
    });
    console.log(this.state.cities)
  }
 
  render() {
    let postList = this.state.cities.map(city => {
      return(
        <div key = {city.id}>
          <p>
            <Link to = {'/'+city.id}>{city.name}</Link>
          </p>
        </div>
      )
    })
    return(
      <div className = 'align'>All Facilities (NCAL)
        <div className="hr-sect">OR</div>
        <div className = 'Modal'>
          {postList}
        </div>
        <FacilityModal cityname = {this.props} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class ArticleList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articles: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return axios.get('GET_ARTICLES_URL').then(response => {
      this.setState({
        articles: response.data
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.articles.map(a => <li><a href={a.url}>{a.title}</a></li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

// ---------

import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';

jest.mock('axios', () => {
  const exampleArticles = [
    { title: 'test article', url: 'test url' }
  ];
  
  return {
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(exampleArticles)),
  };
});

const axios = require('axios');

it('fetch articles on #componentDidMount', () => {
  const app = shallow(<App />);
  app
    .instance()
    .componentDidMount()
    .then(() => {
      expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('articles_url');
      expect(app.state()).toHaveProperty('articles', [
        { title: 'test article', url: 'test url' }
      ]);
      done();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for this answer! any idea why switching to the `mount()` method (ie: `app = mount(<App />)`) would then throw the error `cannot read property componentDidMount of null`? When I use shallow, no issues, according to Jest docs, the `instance()` method returns null under the same conditions.

Answer (score 0):

1) Extract the API call in another method that returns the promise(for eg: fetchCities()) for ease of testing.

2) Mock the axios node module with Jest. Refer docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules

3) Use Enzyme to get a reference to your component: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/shallow.html

Once that's in place, you can verify if the state is set correctly. For eg:

```
test('should fetch users', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Home/>);
  const resp = {data: [{cities: ['NY']}]};

  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp);

  wrapper.instance().fetchCities().then(resp => {
     expect(wrapper.state('cities')).toEqual(resp.data.cities);
  });

});
```

How do i improve this answer? It is not what i am expecting as response which is name of the cities.

axios.js (seperate function for promise)

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  get: () => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      data: [
        {
          id: 0,
          name: 'Santa Clara'
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Fremont'
        }
      ]
    });
  }
};
```

Home.test.js (actual test file)

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow,configure } from 'enzyme';
import Home from './Home';
import axios from 'axios';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({adapter:new Adapter()});

jest.mock('axios');


describe('Home component', () => {
  describe('when rendered', () => {
    it('should fetch a list of cities', () => {
      const getSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');
      const cityInstance = shallow(
        <Home/>
      );
      expect(getSpy).toBeCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried with a separate method for the promise but still not able to get the answer as expected. (List of all cities)

Comment: Are you getting an assertion error? Can you share that test case as well along with the failure logs?

Comment: I am not getting any error. It is passing and showing that 2 cities on the console. Our idea should be to see whether our API request is successful or not. This is the only files I have written to test this functionality. And I should mention the call for that GET request too but not sure where it would go.

Comment: The test in Home.test.js file asserts if the api call is initiated or not. To assert the response of the call, you will have to write another test case. In this you'll need to manually call the 'axios.get' method and then assert the value of `wrapper.state('cities')` in the callback of `.then()`