# React JS Jest Unit Testing Enzyme Set state for testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing a jest and enzyme unit testing for a react js component that uses Reflux.

I finally got the test to check the componentdidmount and check the component with the folloiwng

```
**const onWillMount = jest.fn()
MyComponent.protoType.componentWillMount = onWillMount
mount(<MyComponent/>)
expect(onWillMount).toHaveBeenCalled(1)**
```

but I have state variables which are populated before it passed back the rendering

using jest and  enzyme, how to do set the state variable like this.state.myList

I am getting the jest error myList of null.

I tried MyComponent.prototype.setState but that did not work

Any help is great appreciated. Thanks

```
export default class MyComponent extends Reflux.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.stores= ['myStore']
    this.storeKeys = ['myDataList']
  }

  compentDidMount() {
    myAction.getMyList()
  }

  render() {
    const hasData = !_.isNil(this.state.myList)
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest/Enzyme Unit Test on Axios Requests in ComponentDidMount()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745388/jest-enzyme-unit-test-on-axios-requests-in-componentdidmount)